# Ionic framework ionicView.entered event fired twice

Tags: javascript, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I'm playing with this ionicView events that are fired whenever the views become active, and I'm using the side menu template that you can re-use when creating the project. It seems that if I put a listener for the $ionicView.entered event in the AppCtrl (the one used by the side menu template, which belongs to an abstract state in the ui-router configuration) it gets called twice in a row for any of the subviews (like, when using app.someotherview as a state).

I don't know if this is the expected behavior because from the documentation I would expect it to only fire once, no matter if I change the subview (the menuContent view).

I'd like to know if this is expected behavior and if so, how do I get to have an event fired only once every time it gets to show the side menu template.

This is what I've got written:

This is from the application module:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {
  $stateProvider

  .state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

  .state('app.overview', {
    url: "/overview",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/overview.html",
        controller: 'OverviewCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('login', {
    url: "/login",
    templateUrl: "templates/identificationscreen.html",
    controller: "IdentificationCtrl"
  })

  .state('app.agenda', {
    url: "/agenda",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/agenda.html",
        controller: 'AgendaCtrl'
      }
    }
  });

  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('credentialsInjector');

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
```

Then the AppCtrl is this:

```
angular.module('dashboard.controllers.app', [])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, authService, $state) {
    $scope.logout = function() {
        authService.logout();
        $state.go('login');
    };

    $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(){ //This is fired twice in a row
        console.log("App view (menu) entered.");
        console.log(arguments); 
    });

    $scope.$on('$ionicView.leave', function(){ //This just one when leaving, which happens when I logout
        console.log("App view (menu) leaved.");
        console.log(arguments);
    });
});
```

The menu template:

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
  <ion-side-menu-content edge-drag-threshold="true">
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">APPoint!</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/overview">
          Overview
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/agenda">
          Agenda
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ng-click="logout()">
          Logout
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Comment: @andrian you got solution for this issue?

Answer (score 10):

A simple workaround is:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(ev) {
    if(ev.targetScope !== $scope)
        return;
    // Your code which should only run once
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But <del>I want to</del> now I know why it works this way. Specifically, it's weird that `ev.targetScope.id === $scope.id` even if `ev.targetScope !== $scope` !

Answer (score 2):

The best option that I found to simulate onEnter event was to use in view controller :

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
if (toState.name == "stateName")
    doSomething();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can globally disable the caching mechanism used by ionic by doing:

```
$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);
```

I haven't tried that on my own though.

Else, the best way that worked for me was doing

```
$scope.$on("$ionicView.afterLeave", function () {
     $ionicHistory.clearCache();
});
```

This is to clear the cache before leaving the view to re-run controller every time you enter back again.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$ionicView.afterEnter`. That fires only once for me.
[URL](http://blog.ionic.io/navigating-the-changes/)

Answer (score 0):

At first I used [Florian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35960728/122441) but noticed that in my case it's just a symptom of a root problem, because this doesn't happen to all controllers, just this one.

In my case, it happens because I was trying to [incrementally migrate from Ionic/AngularJS v1 to Ionic/AngularJS v2](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/migration/).

I have added `controllerAs` in my template:

```
<ion-view view-title="Avatar » Instruments" ng-controller="AvatarInstrumentsCtrl as vm">
```

but I forgot to remove the controller reference in my `app.js` :

```
  .state('app.avatar-instruments', {
      url: "/avatar/instruments",
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: "templates/avatar/instruments.html",
          controller: 'AvatarInstrumentsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
```

So in my case the solution is:

```
  .state('app.avatar-instruments', {
      url: "/avatar/instruments",
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: "templates/avatar/instruments.html"
        }
      }
    })
```